# In excel selecting rows by variables

Tags: excel, vba

After researching I did not find an example where in this macro I can substitute variables for the fixed row numbers.

```
Rows("14:26").Select
```

I'm building a form with multiple pages.  On each page after it has been added I want to go in and change the row height for this range of rows.  I can calculate the start and end rows with no problem, but I have not figured out how to rewrite this line with variables

I was hoping something like this would have worked

```
Rows(sRow:eRow).Select
```

or

```
Rows("sRow:eRow").Select
```

or

```
Rows(sRow, eRow).Select
```

Comment: `Rows(sRow & ":" & eRow").Select`

Comment: Yep that works just have to remove the extra " after eRow.  State this as an Answer to my question and I will mark an accept so you get credit

Comment: Go ahead and accept @FelipeRosa he took the time to explain the "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form is:

```
Rows(sRow & ":" & eRow).Select
```

Explanation: you need to concatenate your two variables with a colon because this is the format the row selection function expects.